# How do I get references to large amount of buttons in android?

Tags: java, android

In my xml layout file I have 81 buttons like this:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button11"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

I know that I can get reference like this:

```
playButtons[0][0] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button11);
playButtons[0][1] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button12);
```

and so on, but how can I do it efficiently?

edit:

I want to fill my playButtons matrix with references to XML buttons in for loop like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i<9; i++){ 
      for(int k = 0; k<9; k++){ 
            playButtons[i][k] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button11);}}
```

But I don't know how to change button11 to button12 and so on.

Comment: do you want to get all references at once? or are you looking for a more efficient way?

Comment: Can't you create all these buttons programmatically instead of doing this in your XML?

Comment: As I edited above I want them all at once. Is there way to make them programmatically and put in layout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want. You have to name the buttons as button01,button02,button03,etc.

```
 Button[][] playButtons = null;
        Class id=R.id.class;
         Field field = null;
         for(int i = 0; i<9; i++){ 
              for(int k = 0; k<9; k++){ 
                  try {
                    field = id.getField("button"+i+""+k);

                playButtons[i][k] = (Button) findViewById(field.getInt(null));
                } catch (NoSuchFieldException e2) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e2.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


              }}
```

Comment: Correct. In my mind I had solution for this looking just like your. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered a listview or gridview? If you could use either of those that would be much more efficient. If not you are going to have to declare each button one by one but if you use the playButtons array you can use a loop to apply changes to all the buttons for example

```
for(int i = 0;i<playButtons.length;i++){
  playButtons[0][i].setOnClickListener(this);
 }
```

and this would be the most efficient way I could think of...

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest you to use this syntax to your IDs, so you won't get confused with large amout of IDs on your app:

```
android:id="@+id/your_file_name_widgetName_whatYourWidgetDo
```

Example of a button that saves a settings preset, inside a layout file called **menu_settings.xml**

```
android:id="@+id/menu_settings_button_savePreset"
```

When I have a lot of buttons on my XML file, I register it on array, like this:

```
final int[] BUTTON_ID = { 

    R.id.myId, R.id.anotherId, R.id.otherId,
    R.id.moreId, R.id.anotherAnotherId

};

final int BUTTONS_COUNT = BUTTON_ID.lenght;

Button[] button;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

    ...

    button = new Button[BUTTONS_COUNT];

    for(int i = 0; i < BUTTONS_COUNT; i++){

        button[i] = (Button) findViewById(BUTTONS_ID[i]);

        button[i].setOnClickListener(this); // your class should implements View.onClickListener to use "this" as argument

    }

}
```

You told you have 81 buttons on your layout, the `findViewById()` inside `for` loop will result on low perfomanced loop, I suggest you to add the `android:onClick = "methodName"` attr to your buttons on xml file, so you don't need to use `findViewById()` for each.

To work with your buttons, just add the following to your Activity class, and do whatever you want:

```
public void methodName(View v){

    Button b = (Button) v;

    int ID = b.getId();


    if(ID == R.id.buttonId){

        //DO SOMETHING FOR THIS BUTTON

    }


    else if(ID == R.id.anotherButtonId){

        //DO SOMETHING FOR THIS BUTTON

    }

    ...

}
```

But think about it: you do need so many buttons on your layout? Think in a better app architecture, 81 buttons can be very heavy to a single Thread.

I hope you get the idea!

Comment: Thanks! That was helpful. The reason I have 81 buttons is just because they are my board for Gmoku game. I thought that with my buttons matrix I will be able to mark each button in constans time.

Comment: Your're welcome, I'm glad you found what you want up there, good coding!